# Resolve http requests before page load

Tags: angularjs, http

I want to get data from my server via `$http` request in Angularjs and only after the `promise` gets `resolved` use `ng-repeat` the loop over the data.
I have `SPA` (singal page app) without `$routeProvider`(only simple tabs).
How can I load the data before `ng-repeat` starts?

Comment: You can use boolean variable until it's become true make it ng-hide.

Comment: Can you post a simple example?

Comment: If you don't want to hide the ng-repeat then you can do something like display progress bar on the page and once you get the data from service, fill the data in the collection of ng-repeart and hide that progress bar.

Comment: think the angular way. Why do you need to wait?? you just bind your data to a variable inside the scope and whenever the data loads, the digest cycle will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks, I choose the Angular way and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ng-if="items.length" to restrict ng-repeat run before data populated.

```
<div ng-if="items.length">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the use of  `ng-show` would be better as it won't cause the dom to re-render when he actually gets the data. As for the code, its almost the same as Gokul's answer, just replace the `ng-if` with the `ng-show`.

Also, no real need to add another variable just to hide/show. If the `expression` results in a falsy value, the element will be hidden.

--- edit ---

Another approach would be to resolve the value via the router. That way, the view will only be loaded once the http promise is resolved.